# Check for new folder after running bat commands

Tags: batch-file, directory

Is there a way to check if a new folder (exact name is unknown) has been created inside a specific parent folder as a result of running previous commands in bat file? If yes - run one more command with the full path to a new folder as an argument to that command.

Right now I am using a folder monitoring software to run another bat if new folder is created. I would like to have just one script performing both tasks.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think so cmd can monitor file system you can use powershell [filesystemonitor](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)

Comment: I don't really need a true monitoring, just check for new folders at the end of bat file. Maybe, when bat file runs, a txt file can be created with folder names and if next time it runs there is a folder non existant in txt, it's path can be used as an argument? I am sure this can be accomplished with cmd bat, I just don't know the syntax for that.

Comment: `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` is a live until your powershell session alive but bat file you must run each time to get change you can do it by bat file just `dir /ad >list.txt` then get list with loop check with new dir /ad if another one in new dir that not exist list you can notify by echo new file created or deleted but not better than powershell monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `root_folder` location on the second line 
     @echo off
     set "root_folder=C:\something"

```
 setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 set counter=1
 for /d /r  "%root_folder%" %%a in (*) do (
    set "dirs[!counter!]=%%~sa" >nul
    set /a counter=counter+1
 )

 rem ############################
 rem #  call your code here !!! #
 rem ############################
 call commands.bat

 rem for /l %%l in (1,1,!counter!) do (
 rem    dir /x /b /s /a:d "%root_folder%" | findstr /i "dirs[%%l]" 
 rem )

 set flag=0
 for /d /r  "%root_folder%" %%a in (*) do (
   set dirs[|find  /i "%%~sa" >nul 2>nul ||(
      echo "%%~sa" is a new folder
      set flag=1
   )
 )

 if %flag% equ 0 (
    echo no new folders
 )
```

Comment: Thank you all. Npocmaka's solution worked great. Powershell is also working but it is an overkill for my needs. Will decide what to use. Thanks again!

Comment: I did some testing. It appears this script returns a short name if a new folder contains spaces. So echo "%%~sa" returns "C:\Temp\NEWDIR~1" is a new folder if folder name is NEWDIR NEW. I will need a folder name for further processing if %flag% is 1.

Comment: @astep  - to work with full names change `%%~sa` to `%%~a` . It should continue to work , just I think the shortpats are safer for the script.

Comment: @astep you can call another file or subroutine if there's a new folder with the folder as an argument just after the line where the `flag` is set to `1`

Comment: it is working now. Thank you. However, there is an error “Environment variable dirs[ not defined” when new folder has spaces, but script continues to work.